# How to Grep more than one line to get all the thread content

Tags: regex, unix, grep

How to Grep more than one line to get all the lines under that thread.
I already tried grep -A,-B,-C , but that seems to get more than or sometimes less than what i need.

```
$cat text.txt
=====================================================================
[11-23-18 10:07:01:119]::Thread(ABC):request returned

[11-23-18 10:07:01:120]::Thread(ABC):Sending packet 'POST /aq/ConManager HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:192.168.1.1
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1149
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
SOAPAction: ""

[11-23-18 10:07:01:121]::Thread(XYZ): doing request

[11-23-18 10:07:01:122]::Thread(XYZ): request returned

================================================================
```

Now, if I use `grep -A 10 ABC text.txt`, it will output all other lines like `thread XYZ`. Wherein I only want to output all ABC thread and it's lines.And If I use only grep it will not output succeeding lines after the ABC thread.

Comment: Use the `{}` button in the question editor to format data and code, Also, please add the expected output for the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
awk '/^\[[^][]*]::Thread\(ABC\)/,/^$/' file > newfile
```

It matches  a block of lines between two patterns, the second one matches an empty line and the first one matches:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\[` - a `[`
- `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` -  a `]`
- `::Thread\(ABC\)` - a `::Thread(ABC)` substring

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/5Wc8NA).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one that may or may not be what you were looking for:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '/ABC/' file
```

Output:

```
=====================================================================
[11-23-18 10:07:01:119]::Thread(ABC):request returned
[11-23-18 10:07:01:120]::Thread(ABC):Sending packet 'POST /aq/ConManager HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:192.168.1.1
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1149
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
SOAPAction: ""
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '  # use empty records as record separators
/ABC/             # if there is ABC in the record, print it
' file
```